# Linux Device Tree: Touch controller failing i2c test

Tags: embedded-linux, i2c, device-tree

## Context

I am using an i.MX6 ULL application processor with a Goodix 9271 touch-screen display. The display has been added to the device tree and is working correctly. I now wanted to add the touch controller, which is connected to my application processor via I²C. I therefore added

1. A new node under my I²C node which adds the controller as a device on the bus.
2. A new pin control group for the application processor to interface with the touch controller

I have enumerated them here:

```dts
/* #1: Device node on the I2C bus */
&i2c1 {
    clock_frequency = <100000>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c1>;
    status = "okay";

    /* Awesome new touch controller */
    gt9271_ts@5d {
        compatible = "goodix,gt9271";          /* Device tree binding */ 
        reg = <0x5d>;                          /* I2C bus address */
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_gt9271_ts_gpio>; /* Custom pinctrl group node */
        interrupt-parent = <&gpio4>;
        interrupts = <16,0>;                   /* GPIO 4 + pin 16 + active high */       
        reset-gpios = <&gpio4 12 0>;           /* GPIO 4 + Pin 12 + active high */
        touchscreen-size-x = <1200>;
        touchscreen-size-y = <800>;
        touchscreen-inverted-x;
        touchscreen-inverted-y;
    };

    /* ... */
};

/* #2: Pin control group */
&iomuxc {

    pinctrl_gt9271_ts_gpio: gt9271_ts_gpiogrp {
        fsl,pins = <
            MX6UL_PAD_NAND_DQS__GPIO4_IO16        0x80000000 /* Interrupt */
            MX6UL_PAD_NAND_READY_B__GPIO4_IO12    0x80000000 /* Reset */
        >;
    };

    /* ... */
};
```

##### Explanation: bus address

The device data sheet, available [here](https://www.distec.de/fileadmin/pdf/produkte/Touchcontroller/DDGroup/GT9271_Datasheet.pdf), indicates that two slave addresses are supported: `0xBA/0xBB` and `0x28/0x29`. The device is set to use `0xBA/0xBB` adjusted for 7-bit addressing as recommended in [this binding](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/input/touchscreen/goodix.txt), (so the address assigned in the node is actually `0x5d`).

##### Explanation: control pins

The I²C reset and interrupt are connected (respectively) to GPIO 4, pin 16, and GPIO 4, pin 12. These are reserved for NAND but NAND is not being used with this processor so the pins are free.

## Problem

Unfortunately, the touchscreen controller configuration I have added is failing on boot with an I²C related message. I am greeted on boot with the following:

```auto
[    2.118110] Goodix-TS 0-005d: 0-005d supply AVDD28 not found, using dummy regulator
[    2.126059] Goodix-TS 0-005d: 0-005d supply VDDIO not found, using dummy regulator
[    2.134510] Goodix-TS 0-005d: i2c test failed attempt 1: -6
[    2.177733] Goodix-TS 0-005d: i2c test failed attempt 2: -6
[    2.217377] Goodix-TS 0-005d: I2C communication failure: -6
```

I have attempted to search the error code (-6) but find sparse to non-existent search results online. I've checked that the connector is physically there and it seems to be.

What steps might I take to diagnose such an error code?

Comment: Error codes (up to ~40) are standard POSIX ones, so 6 means ENXIO https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h#L10 which is **in Linux kernel** basically the error when required IRQ line(s) not found. But it seems you already understood this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as follows:

1. The [documentation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/input/touchscreen/goodix.txt) states that I should include the property in the format `irq-gpios`. I previously thought I only needed the `interrupts` property. After adding `irq-gpios = <&gpio4 16 0>;`, the device passed the I2C test.
2. I disabled `touchscreen-inverted-x;`, and `touchscreen-inverted-y;` by removing those lines. I had incorrectly assumed I needed to do that originally.

##### Verdict:

Try to follow the documentation precisely.

Comment: It might be that your GPIO doesn't have **"interrupc-controller"** property in its node. Or driver is written in a way that it explicitly requires GPIO interrupt to be provided via GPIO property rather than IRQ phandle.

Comment: @0andriy I think it was correctly configured, what basically was wrong was that I wasn't 100% using the suggested properties for the bindings I found. I was specifying the `interrupts` property, but not the `irq-gpios` one. I thought only one would be enough. But thanks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: As far as I know the I2C framework can fetch proper interrupt line from the reference. GPIO interrupts usually are used as auxiliary ones or for backward compatibility.

Comment: I have read the link you posted, it seems that it’s optional and depends on what it does when configured as output. Maybe you missed **reset** GPIO. Without schematic of the electrical connection it is hard to say.

Comment: @0andriy Hmm, well then I don't know quite what fixed it (if indeed that property was optional). Maybe I missed a chance I'd made unconsciously.